# Using contstructors in a class with variables in a base class c++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor

I am trying to use constructor in a class, which the variables that I am assigning the inputs are defined in a bass class. I am using inheritance but still getting an error. This is the code:

```
class Machine_Items {
public:
    string item;
    float price;
    int quantity;
};

class Cart : Machine_Items {
public:
    Cart() = default;
    Cart(string userItem, float userPrice, int userQuantity) :
        item(userItem)), price(userPrice), quantity(userQuantity) {};
};
```

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: So which is the error you are getting?

Comment: When you get a compiler error, paste the exact error message. Also, looks like you have an extra `)` there. Typo?

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize those variables in the base class, then you can call the base class's constructor from the derived class

```
class Machine_Items{
public:
    Machine_Items(string userItem, float userPrice, int userQuantity)
    : item(userItem), price(userPrice), quantity(userQuantity) { }

    string item;
    float price;
    int quantity;
};

class Cart : public Machine_Items
{
public:
    Cart() = default;
    Cart(string userItem, float userPrice, int userQuantity)
    : Machine_Items(userItem, userPrice, userQuantity) {}
};
```